# Adding Context to Django View Causing My Highcharts Map to Disappear

Tags: javascript, html, django, highcharts, django-views

This is my first Django project, and I am working on a Django html template that should contain a Chart.JS bar graph (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html) alongside a Highcharts drilldown map of the US (https://www.highcharts.com/demo/maps/map-drilldown).

I've successfully implemented my Chart.JS bar graph and passed data to it from our AWS RDS. But now when I try to implement even just the stock Highcharts code from their website, the map fails to render at all.  After trying to isolate the problem, I've found that the map does render if I simply delete "context" from the return statement in my view (i.e. delete "context" from the final line in my first block of code below). But this obviously then inhibits my bar graph from rendering.  I think I must be missing something with how the highcharts data is loaded in the presence of other context data, but I've been unable to fix it such that both the graph and map render.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My Django View:

```
def index(request):
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=xxxx,
        user=xxxx,
        password=xxxx,
        database=xxxx
    )
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("WITH CS1 AS (SELECT cts.Name, cts.State, m.Frequently, m.Always FROM Masks m JOIN Counties cts ON (m.FIPS = cts.FIPS)) SELECT CS1.State, AVG((CS1.Frequently+CS1.Always)*100) AS Perc_High_Frequency FROM CS1 WHERE CS1.State<>'Puerto Rico' GROUP BY CS1.State ORDER BY Perc_High_Frequency DESC")
    tempList = mycursor.fetchall()
    statesMaskName = [item[0] for item in tempList]
    statesMaskPerc = [item[1] for item in tempList]
    context={'statesMaskName':statesMaskName, 'statesMaskPerc':statesMaskPerc}
    return render(request,'index.html', context)
```

The relevant HTML/JS:

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="fixed-header">
            <h1>COVID-19 Sentiment and Mask Practices</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="col-lg-3" style="float: left;  max-height: 6500px;max-width:400px;overflow: scroll; overflow-x:hidden;">
                <div style="background-color: #17202A;">
                    <span style="color: #F7F9F9; text-align: center;"><h4>% Population Who "Frequently" or "Always" Wear Masks When In Public Within 6" of Others (as of July 2-14, 2020)</h4></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    
                    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="selectState">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="col-lg-4" style="float: left; max-height: 3000px;">
                            <br><br style="line-height: 15px"/>
                            {% for state in statesMaskName %}
                                <table style="border-width: 2px; border: #333;">
                                    <tr>
                                    <input type="submit" value="{{state}}" name="statesMaskName" style="width:130px;">
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            {% endfor%}
                        </div>
                        <div style="float: left;">
                            <canvas id="myChart" height="1360" width="250"></canvas>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>        
            <div class="col-lg-6">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
    </body>



    <!--my updated code for chartjs graph-->
    <script>
        const labels = {{statesMaskName|safe}};
        const data = {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{
                label: '% Population',
                color: 'orange',
                backgroundColor: 'orange',
                borderColor: 'orange',
                data: {{statesMaskPerc|safe}},
            }]
        };
        const config = {
            type: 'bar',
            data,
            options: {
                indexAxis: 'y',
                color: 'white',
                scales: {
                    y: {
                        grid: {
                            color: '#b3b1ad',
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            color: 'white',
                        },
                        display: false
                    },
                    x: {
                        grid: {
                            color: '#b3b1ad',
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            color: 'white',
                            // Include a % sign in the ticks
                            callback: function(value, index, values) {
                            return value + '%';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        var myChart = new Chart(
            document.getElementById('myChart'),
            config
        );
    </script>

<!--stock code for highcharts map-->
<div id="usMap" style="height: 500px; min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/offline-exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/us/us-all.js"></script>

<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript">
  /*
TODO:
- Check data labels after drilling. Label rank? New positions?
*/

let data = Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps['countries/us/us-all']);
const separators = Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps['countries/us/us-all'], 'mapline');

// Set drilldown pointers
data.forEach((d, i) => {
  d.drilldown = d.properties['hc-key'];
  d.value = i; // Non-random bogus data
});

function getScript(url, cb) {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = url;
  script.onload = cb;
  document.head.appendChild(script);
}

// Instantiate the map
Highcharts.mapChart('usMap', {
  chart: {
    events: {
      drilldown: function (e) {
        if (!e.seriesOptions) {
          const chart = this,
            mapKey = 'countries/us/' + e.point.drilldown + '-all';

          // Handle error, the timeout is cleared on success
          let fail = setTimeout(() => {
            if (!Highcharts.maps[mapKey]) {
              chart.showLoading('<i class="icon-frown"></i> Failed loading ' + e.point.name);
              fail = setTimeout(() => {
                chart.hideLoading();
              }, 1000);
            }
          }, 3000);

          // Show the spinner
          chart.showLoading('<i class="icon-spinner icon-spin icon-3x"></i>'); // Font Awesome spinner

          // Load the drilldown map
          getScript('https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/' + mapKey + '.js', () => {
            data = Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps[mapKey]);

            // Set a non-random bogus value
            data.forEach((d, i) => {
              d.value = i;
            });

            // Hide loading and add series
            chart.hideLoading();
            clearTimeout(fail);
            chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, {
              name: e.point.name,
              data: data,
              dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.name}'
              }
            });
          });
        }

        this.setTitle(null, { text: e.point.name });
      },
      drillup: function () {
        this.setTitle(null, { text: '' });
      }
    }
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Highcharts Map Drilldown'
  },

  subtitle: {
    text: '',
    floating: true,
    align: 'right',
    y: 50,
    style: {
      fontSize: '16px'
    }
  },

  colorAxis: {
    min: 0,
    minColor: '#E6E7E8',
    maxColor: '#005645'
  },

  mapNavigation: {
    enabled: true,
    buttonOptions: {
      verticalAlign: 'bottom'
    }
  },

  plotOptions: {
    map: {
      states: {
        hover: {
          color: '#EEDD66'
        }
      }
    }
  },

  series: [{
    data: data,
    name: 'USA',
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      format: '{point.properties.postal-code}'
    }
  }, {
    type: 'mapline',
    data: separators,
    color: 'silver',
    enableMouseTracking: false,
    animation: {
      duration: 500
    }
  }],

  drilldown: {
    activeDataLabelStyle: {
      color: '#FFFFFF',
      textDecoration: 'none',
      textOutline: '1px #000000'
    },
    drillUpButton: {
      relativeTo: 'spacingBox',
      position: {
        x: 0,
        y: 60
      }
    }
  }
});

</script>
        
</html>
```

Comment: Did you check your console for any errors? Also don't do this: `{{statesMaskName|safe}}`, it is unsafe and leaves you vulnerable to XSS attacks. Instead try using the [`json_script` template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script)

Comment: Have you seen this blog article about integrating Django and highcharts? https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/create-a-dashboard-using-highcharts-and-django/ it includes all proper patterns

Comment: Thank you, both. I had not inspected the webpage's console yet.  As embarrassing as it is, this is my first project and I had not noticed the error message.  It immediately gave me the answer for my issue.  The "data" identifier in the highcharts script had already been declared in the chartjs script.  I was under the impression that the scripts' scope did not overlap, but I guess that was my mistake.  Thanks again for the quick responses.